# Jenkins declarative pipeline: input with conditional steps without blocking the executor

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-declarative-pipeline

I'm trying to get the following features to work in Jenkins' Declarative Pipeline syntax:

- Conditional execution of certain stages only on the `master` branch
- `input` to ask for user confirmation to deploy to a staging environment
- While waiting for confirmation, it doesn't block an executor

Here's what I've ended up with:

```
pipeline {
  agent none
  stages {
    stage('1. Compile') {
      agent any
      steps {
        echo 'compile'
      }
    }
    stage('2. Build & push Docker image') {
      agent any
      when {
        branch 'master'
      }
      steps {
        echo "build & push docker image"
      }
    }
    stage('3. Deploy to stage') {
      when {
        branch 'master'
      }
      input {
        message "Deploy to stage?"
        ok "Deploy"
      }
      agent any
      steps {
        echo 'Deploy to stage'
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The problem is that stage 2 needs the output from 1, but this is not available when it runs. If I replace the various `agent` directives with a global `agent any`, then the output is available, but the executor is blocked waiting for user input at stage 3. And if I try and combine 1 & 2 into a single stage, then I lose the ability to conditionally run some steps only on `master`.

Is there any way to achieve all the behaviour I'm looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `stash` command at the end of your first step and then `unstash` when you need the files

I think these are available in the [snippet generator](https://jenkins.io/blog/2016/05/31/pipeline-snippetizer/)

As per the [documentation](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/#code-stash-code-stash-some-files-to-be-used-later-in-the-build)

> Saves a set of files for use later in the same build, generally on
>   another node/workspace. Stashed files are not otherwise available and
>   are generally discarded at the end of the build. Note that the stash
>   and unstash steps are designed for use with small files. For large
>   data transfers, use the External Workspace Manager plugin, or use an
>   external repository manager such as Nexus or Artifactory